# unable to get loop to work properly

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class addinggamedowhile
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        Random r = new Random ();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = r.nextInt(20)+1;
        int y = r.nextInt(20)+1;

        int sum = x + y;
        int guess;
        System.out.println("===========");
        System.out.println("Adding Game");
        System.out.println("===========");
        System.out.println();

    int tries = 0;
    for (int games = 0; games < 10; games++)
    {
        do
        {
        System.out.print (x + " + " + y + " = ");
        guess = s.nextInt();

        if (guess != sum && tries < 2)
        {
        System.out.println("Not quite. Try again!");
        System.out.println();
        tries++;
        }
        else
        System.out.println("Not quite. The answer is " +sum+ ".");
        System.out.println();
       }
    while (guess != sum);
    System.out.println("Congratulations. You got it!");
    System.out.println();
}

}}
```

I'm having trouble with this loop. I cannot get the loop to terminate when I want it to. It's supposed to last for only ten "guesses". In addition, when the user gets the question right, my else statement is also executed. The other thing is that once the user gets the question correct, or does not get the question correct in the three times it is allowed, a new set of numbers are supposed to appear. I have not been able to get that to execute properly either. I've tried different things that worked well, but the requirement for the project is to use a do while loop.

Comment: When would `while (guess != sum)`?  Looks like you are incremeting tries:  `tries++`

Comment: Don't forget to put a tag for the language, and work on your indenting here, the code is pretty difficult to read as is.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
do {
    //your code here
} while (guess != sum && tries <= 10);
```

The loop will keep going until the sum is correct or the number of tries is exhausted.  Increment tries by one every time the loop iterates.

Then, after completion (i.e. outside the loop), do a check to see if the guess is the correct sum or if the tries were exhausted and print out the response accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the `break` keyword when the guess is correct or no more tries. Also, you should probably reset your tries variable inside the outer for loop (so that it get's reset at the beginning f each game).